# Zend Framework 2, Module.php and getting value of param

Tags: zend-framework2

In Module.php I have a some code (simplified version):

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module{
    public $somevariable = 'test';
    public function onBootstrap( MvcEvent $e ) {
        $this->somevariable = 'test2';
    }
    public function getValue(){
        return $this->somevariable;
    }
}
```

Next, I want to get value from variable "somevariable" in template layout.phtml. I do this as follows:

```
echo Application\Module::getValue();
```

but this doesn't work. What is wrong with that?

P.S. I never programmed much in PHP, so maybe I missed something :-(

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$e->getViewModel()->setVariable('somevariable', 'somethingvalue');
```

and in the view :

```
echo $this->layout()->somevariable;
```

for detail, see this article : http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/zend-framework-2-mvcevent-layout-view-get-namespace/

Comment: Ok, seems that way of passing variables working well in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is just a string it doesn't make much sense to go with that approach. And please don't take this offensively, but if you don't have much experience in PHP (you tried to call a static function that is not static), then i wonder why you would start learning PHP with such a high class framework.

And if still you insist on doing that, please follow the [official Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html) and read yourself through the whole QuickStart again and again. Check out some of the [Modules](http://modules.zendframework.com) out there and see how they do stuff.

Try to do the easy stuff first until you hit those points where you **really** need such functionality.

Comment: "If a variable is just a string it doesn't make much sense to go with that approach." - maybe, but somehow the value of property must be passed.

"if you don't have much experience in PHP (you tried to call a static function that is not static), then i wonder why you would start learning PHP with such a high class framework." - because I worked with ZF1 little bit, but very long time ago. Just want to refresh some knowledge and go forward. I think that there is nothing wrong to use ZF, even if this is high class framework.